# Django-templates: how to make list in templates

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, django-templates

The part of my template:

```
{% if True %}
<div class="container" id="timeline-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-timeline">
            {% for player in room.player.all %}
                {% for level in player.leavel.all %}
                    <div class="timeline">
                        <div class="timeline-content">
                            <span class="date">
                                <span class="month">{{ level.create.time }}</span>
                                <span class="year">{{ level.create.date|date:"d.m"  }}</span>
                            </span>
                            <h2 class="title" style="background: #02a2dd;"><span class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ player.player.email }} теперь {{ level.leavel }} уровня
                            </h2>
                            <p class="description">Игрок {{ player.player.email }} изменил уровень</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I wanna make a list for the level of all players from the room.player.all. So I need these two cycles to end and after their ending I gotta have a list with all levels of all players for my timelines

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you revise for clarity?

Comment: When you say "make a list", do you mean the html elements `<ol>` and `<ul>`?